# Get the error code from tweepy exception instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I'm new to python and I'm trying to use a library. It raises an exception, and I am trying to identify which one. This is what I am trying:

```
except tweepy.TweepError as e:
    print e
    print type(e)
    print e.__dict__
    print e.reason
    print type(e.reason)
```

This is what I am getting:

```
[{u'message': u'Sorry, that page does not exist', u'code': 34}]
<class 'tweepy.error.TweepError'>
{'reason': u"[{u'message': u'Sorry, that page does not exist', u'code': 34}]", 'response': <httplib.HTTPResponse instance at 0x00000000029CEAC8>}
[{u'message': u'Sorry, that page does not exist', u'code': 34}]
<type 'unicode'>
```

Im trying to get to that code. I have tried e.reason.code with no success and I have no idea what to try.

Comment: Yeah - I might have misread that one - What about `e.reason[0]['code']` ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "descargar.py", line 70, in <module>
    print e.reason[0]['code']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @alecxe Sorry, this was some time ago, I don't remember what I did, but i did get the code (as I wanted). Nevertheless, your answer works,  so I have accept it :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about this?

```
except tweepy.TweepError as e:
    print e.message[0]['code']  # prints 34
    print e.args[0][0]['code']  # prints 34
```

Comment: It seems to me that since `e` is a list object, that `e.message[0]['code']` wouldn't work. Wouldn't you instead use `e[0]['code']`?

Comment: Actually, now that I look at the github page, tweepError is overriding the print statement with the `__str__` so that may be why I've been having issues. Do you happen to know how `e` is structured?

Comment: e.message is not working anymore. Please check @Jeyekomon answer

Answer (score 24):

Every well-behaved exception derived from the base Exception class [has](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException.args) an `args` attribute (of type `tuple`) that contains arguments passed to that exception. Most of the time only one argument is passed to an exception and can be accessed using `args[0]`.

The argument Tweepy passes to its exceptions has a structure of type `List[dict]`. You can get the error code (type `int`) and the error message (type `str`) from the argument using this code:

```
e.args[0][0]['code']
e.args[0][0]['message']
```

The [TweepError exception class](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/error.py) also provides several additional helpful attributes `api_code`, `reason` and `response`. They are [not documented](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) for some reason even though they are a part of public API.

So you can get the error code (type `int`) also using this code:

```
e.api_code
```

### History:

The error code used to be accessed using `e.message[0]['code']` which no longer works. The `message` attribute has been [deprecated in Python 2.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/) and removed in Python 3.0. Currently you get an error `'TweepError' object has no attribute 'message'`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was going crazy lol The docs are really outdated

Comment: `e.api_code` returns `None`. At least when `status code = 401`, maybe it's a bug.

Comment: @j4n7 Look at the [Twitter API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes). If I understand it right, every response contains a HTTP status code but not every response contains an Error code (API code). API codes are provided only for the most common errors.

Comment: Weirdly enough. Rate limit is not in `e.api_code`. Use the `tweepy.RateLimit` exception. or the `e.args[0][0]['code']`

Comment: How is this not marked as the best answer!! Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Things have changed quite a bit since 2013. The correct answer as of now is to use `e.api_code`.

Answer (score 2):

To get just the error code use the method monq posted.  The following example illustrates how to get both the error code and the message.  I had to extract the message from the e.reason string, if anyone has a better method to retrieve just the message, please share.

Note: This code should work for any error code/reason with the following format.

[{'code': 50, 'message': 'User not found.'}]

```
def getExceptionMessage(msg):
    words = msg.split(' ')

    errorMsg = ""
    for index, word in enumerate(words):
        if index not in [0,1,2]:
            errorMsg = errorMsg + ' ' + word
    errorMsg = errorMsg.rstrip("\'}]")
    errorMsg = errorMsg.lstrip(" \'")

    return errorMsg
```

And you can call it like so:

```
try:
    # Some tweepy api call, ex) api.get_user(screen_name = usrScreenName)
except tweepy.TweepError as e:
    print (e.api_code)
    print (getExceptionMessage(e.reason))
```

Answer (score 1):

As of December 2021 (tweepy v4.4.0) the correct way is:

```
except tweepy.TweepyException as e:
    print(e)
```

source: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/v4.4.0/changelog.html?highlight=TweepError#new-features-improvements

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
except tweepy.TweepError as e:
    print e.response.status
```

Comment: Does it really prints the code of tweepy error (34 in this case)?

Comment: Yes, it prints whichever HTTP status code is returned by the server in the event of an error.

Comment: But, 34 is not a response status code here, it's a twitter error code.

Comment: I see what you mean.  In that case, my solution is incorrect.  Sorry for the confusion.