# python 3: TypeError: ' ' object is not iterable

Tags: python, tweepy

So I am working on a Twitter bot and during the exceptions I run into a error that causes the program to stop. I am not to sure what is causing it.

I've been searching around trying to figure it out but have had no luck.

Any chance someone can spot the issue.

```
except tweepy.error.TweepError as e:
            error_code = list(e)[0][0].get('code')
            if error_code == 327:
                print('no need')

            elif error_code == 88:
                print('wait 16 minutes we have hit limit')
                time.sleep(15 * 60)

            elif error_code == 226:
                print('STOP')
                time.sleep(15 * 60)

            elif error_code == 261:
                print(' banned')
            else:
                print(str(e))
    except AttributeError as e:
            print('Something bad has happened')
    except Error as e:
            print(str(e))
```

the error it give me is the following:

```
 error_code = list(e)[0][0].get('code')
 TypeError: 'TweepError' object is not iterable
```

any help would be great.

Comment: Probably because `list(e)` is failing. Why are you converting an error to a list?

Comment: `list(Exception)` doesn't work.  Are you looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157753/get-the-error-code-from-tweepy-exception-instance)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the error code from tweepy exception instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157753/get-the-error-code-from-tweepy-exception-instance)

Comment: Thank you for that link patrick, i;ll have a read over it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's helpful to post the full stack trace, but in this case it's diagnosable without.

On line 2, you call `list(e)`, but `list` expects something it can iterate over to generate a list. A little Googling on this API leads me to believe what you actually want is the line

```
error_code = e.api_code
```

Comment: Amazing! you are right. I must had been doing it in a outdated way. Thank you alot for that. It is now working perfectly.